# How to Clone OS from HDD to SSD with different sector sizes

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, clone

I have an Asus laptop with a 1TB HDD and I bought an NVMe type SSD recently. I'm using Windows 10 and I want to clone my OS from the HDD to SSD and I'm getting different sector size error for both cloning and image restoring. Even the PC do not list down the SSD to install fesh OS. But using minitool I could create a partition on SSD.

Here are the sector details.

**HDD**:

```
C:\Windows\system32>fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c:
NTFS Volume Serial Number :        0x44bc75efbc75dbbc
NTFS Version      :                3.1
LFS Version       :                2.0
Total Sectors     :                722,824,590  (344.7 GB)
Total Clusters    :                 90,353,073  (344.7 GB)
Free Clusters     :                 54,879,625  (209.3 GB)
Total Reserved Clusters :            1,796,984  (  6.9 GB)
Reserved For Storage Reserve :       1,784,892  (  6.8 GB)
Bytes Per Sector  :                512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :        4096
Bytes Per Cluster :                4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    :  1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment :  0
Mft Valid Data Length :            1.25 GB
Mft Start Lcn  :                   0x00000000000c0000
Mft2 Start Lcn :                   0x0000000000000002
Mft Zone Start :                   0x0000000001791b60
Mft Zone End   :                   0x000000000179e380
MFT Zone Size  :                   200.13 MB
Max Device Trim Extent Count :     512
Max Device Trim Byte Count :       0xffffffff
Max Volume Trim Extent Count :     62
Max Volume Trim Byte Count :       0x40000000
Resource Manager Identifier :      9CBF94F9-6118-11EA-AAFC-00909E9AAD84
```

**SSD:**

```
C:\Windows\system32>fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo d:
NTFS Volume Serial Number :        0x01d72955ab807340
NTFS Version      :                3.1
LFS Version       :                2.0
Total Sectors     :                123,993,599  (473.0 GB)
Total Clusters    :                123,993,599  (473.0 GB)
Free Clusters     :                123,965,910  (472.9 GB)
Total Reserved Clusters :              156,573  (611.6 MB)
Reserved For Storage Reserve :               0  (  0.0 KB)
Bytes Per Sector  :                4096
Bytes Per Physical Sector :        4096
Bytes Per Cluster :                4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    :  4096
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment :  1
Mft Valid Data Length :            1.00 MB
Mft Start Lcn  :                   0x00000000000012c7
Mft2 Start Lcn :                   0x0000000000000026
Mft Zone Start :                   0x0000000000005320
Mft Zone End   :                   0x0000000000011b40
MFT Zone Size  :                   200.13 MB
Max Device Trim Extent Count :     4294967295
Max Device Trim Byte Count :       0xffffffff
Max Volume Trim Extent Count :     62
Max Volume Trim Byte Count :       0xffffffff
Resource Manager Identifier :      AAC332FB-9541-11EB-BB85-BEC52B07437F
```

I spent many hours searching for a solution. Hope someone will help me.

Comment: What is your operating system? How are you doing the cloning? Can you show a screenshot of the error?

Comment: OS is windows 10 as I have mentioned

Comment: I'm Using Macrium Software https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree to clone

Answer (score 4):

After struggling with this for days and trying numerous apps and methods,  [thanks to this post by ArtPog from several years ago](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/how-to-clone-a-drive-when-the-sector-sizes-are-not-the-same-it-is-even-possible.3187520/post-19702836) I finally found an app that can do this: [Casper, by Future Systems](https://www.fssdev.com/products/casper/). It has a 30 day trial that you can use to perform the clone if you don't already own it. I'm impressed with it though because it seems to be the only app in existence — or at least the only one I've found after a wide search — that can make a bootable clone of a Windows partition without doing a sector-by-sector copy.

For the record, here are a list of apps that I tried and *didn't* work, in the hopes that it'll help save someone some time: AOMEI Partition Assistant, Clonezilla, Macrium Reflect, EaseUS Partition Master, `dd` / `ddrescue`, HDClone

Answer (score -3):

I've had the most luck using Aomei Partition Assistant cloning NVMe drives.

Download:
https://www.diskpart.com/free-partition-manager.html

Make Bootable Media:
https://www.diskpart.com/help/make-bootable-cd-wizard.html

Comment: Explaining how to use this tool to solve the problem will make this an answer. Right now this is only a comment as it lacks the information necessary to actually answer the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1135539)

Comment: Also I don't believe AOMEI Partition Assistant can clone a partition on to a drive with different sector sizes. At the very least it wasn't able to do it when I tried.

Comment: I just tried AOMEI Partition Assistant in 2023 - it still doesn't copy between disks with different sector sizes

Comment: I purchased AOMEI software, unfortunately it cannot clone by fixing different sector sizes